# Remove all classes with specified name

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the [Bootstrap Tab](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#nav-tabs) script as:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/calculaties.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Calculaties</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/offertes.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Offertes / bevestigingen</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/bestellingen.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Bestellingen</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/vrachtbrieven.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Vrachtbrieven</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/facturen.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Facturen</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/producten.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Producten</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="clickable"><a href="includes/dossier_detail/certificaten.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Certificaten</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

To get this result:
[image]

To set the tab as active I am using this JS script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Change class on click
$(function() {
  $(".clickable").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});</script>
```

Of course when all tabs are clicked the class `active` added to each tab resulting in
[image]

So to prevent this I have added `removeClass('active')` to my JS script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Change class on click
$(function() {
  $(".clickable").click(function() {
    removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});</script>
```

But now the class active is not set on the current clicked tab. How to solve this?

Comment: I'm surprised you have no error in your console showing up in regards to the `removeClass()` method call. Please first RTFM [**jQuery Documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/) as soon as you have issues using one of their methods, such as [**jQuery removeClass**](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want remove active class from all elements that have it, so you need to select those elements first, you can do something like this:

```
 $(".clickable").click(function() {
    $('.clickable').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have errors in your logs,

> `removeClass` is not defined.

You missed to use for which `elements` you want to remove the `active` class.

Get the `clickable` elements and remove the `active` from it. Because there is a duplicate using `$(".clickable")`, which traverses of the `DOM` two times, you can store it in a variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

  const clickables = $(".clickable");

  clickables.click(function() {
    clickables.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: What if new elements get the `clickable` attribute? You shouldn't "cache" `clickables`, here.

Comment: In this case they are defined

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify which elements you want to remove class

`$(".clickable").removeClass('active');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a jQuery selector to make the `removeClass` actually do something. So you could do:

```
$(function() {
  $(".clickable").click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

Which would get all currently "active" elements and remove the `active` class.

Comment: Now, what if `.active` is used elsewhere on the page? You only want to remove the class from `.clickable` elements.

Comment: @Cerbrus good comment, I would only like to remove it from the class from .clickable elements

Comment: @Muiter: In that case, Dji's answer seems more suitable.